# How to analyze loki storage space?

Tags: grafana-loki

Today the disk space used by Loki has filled up. Is there a dashboard or function in Loki to identify which PODSs generated the most logs?

Something besides [loki-canary](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/loki-canary/#loki-canary)?

I have never used this tool and I don't know if it is right for me

Answer (score 4):

You can analyse the logs generation with the following LogQL:

```
topk(10,count_over_time({filename=~".+"}[1h]))
```

Change the "{filename=~".+"}" stream selector and the "1h" log range as desired.

Comment: A quick explanation about how to interpret those results would be appreciated. All I see if a few lines referencing the loki components.

Comment: `{app_kubernetes_io_component="single-binary", app_kubernetes_io_instance="loki", app_kubernetes_io_name="loki", app_kubernetes_io_part_of="memberlist", cluster="loki", container="loki", controller_revision_hash="loki-988b7cd84", filename="/var/log/pods/monitoring_loki-0_2cdc4a00-961d-47d2-a0a3-6466ba1e0fc2/loki/0.log", job="monitoring/loki-single-binary", namespace="monitoring", pod="loki-0", statefulset_kubernetes_io_pod_name="loki-0", stream="stderr"}`

Comment: Ok, by increasing 10 to an higher value I see my own pods below and not just loki itself. "single-binary" seems to be an aggregate of all others and to be ignored. I think "canary" is what taking all my volume space, so I'll disable that feature.